# Cursor resource not loading properly except built in VS cursors

Tags: visual-studio, winapi, resources, cursor

When I set cursor for my window using built in cursors types such as `IDC_HAND` or `IDC_ARROW` it works fine ex:

```
SetCursor(LoadCursor(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_HAND)));
```

but when importing cursor resource (either downloaded cursor file or custom made or by just creating new cursor resource with VS) then the cursor doesn't chage ex:

```
SetCursor(LoadCursor(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_ICON1)));
```

OR

```
SetCursor(LoadCursor(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_CURSOR1)));
```

resource.h

```
#define IDI_ICON1                       101
#define IDC_CURSOR1                     102
```

resource.rc

```
IDI_ICON1               ICON                    "custom_cursor.cur"
IDC_CURSOR1             CURSOR                  "cursor1.cur"
```

As you see for some reason my custom cursor is saved as "ICON" in resource.rc

`IDC_CURSOR1` is made by VS resource tool but none of them works except built in cursors.

When program runs cursor is not changed, instead black arros are shown, but if using for ex `IDC_ARROW` or `IDC_HAND` then it works.

what could be the cause for this, to not be able to use custom cursors.

btw. I am able to set custom cursor in Windows mouse settings but it doesn't work in VS.

**EDIT:**

I just learned that loading cursor from file works. for example:

```
LoadCursorFromFile(L"custom_cursor.cur");
```

But loading from resource does not work, I prefer to have resources compiled into executable, so I'm still looking for an answer.

Comment: You're not specifying your instance handle. See the docs for LoadCursor.

Comment: Interesting, it works for predefined cursors, but still doesn't work for custom cursor.

Comment: A big part of your problem is that you don't have any error checking code, a problem in 90% on the winapi questions on this site. So you don't know which of the two api calls fail. A crucial learning exercise is for you to rewrite the code to check for errors by inspecting the return values of your function calls.

Comment: Thank you for input, I did call GetLastError() and the error code is "The specified resource type cannot be found in the image file."  I figured out the problem is that nor GIMP nor Photoshop can be used to create cursors, need to use special cursor editor to create cursors and then stuff works!!

Comment: Excellent. It's far more gratifying that you worked this out for yourself by learning useful debugging skills than it would have been for somebody just to tell you what was wrong.